# Displaying associative array data in twig

Tags: theming

Using drupal 8.7.x

I have an associative array that is returned to twig. However I can't seem to get the data displayed.

Associative array:

```
array_push($mealsArray, ["meal" =>
  [
    ['strMeal' => $mealTitle],
    ['strMealThumb' => $mealImage],
    ['mealUrl' => $mealTitleUrl]
  ]
]);
```

Return to twig:

```
return [
  '#theme' => 'recipe_search_block',
  '#meals' => $meals,
  '#ingredientList' => $ingredients,
  'form' => $form,
];
```

In twig I'm trying to display them like this:

```
   <div class="u-row u-margin-top">
    {% for meal in meals %}
      {% for fields in meal %}
        <div class="u-col-md-3 u-col-xs-6">
          <div class="m-recipe">
            <a class="m-recipe__link"href="/recipes/{{ fields["mealUrl"] }}"></a>
            <header class="m-recipe__header u-margin-bottom">
              <h3>{{ fields["strMeal"] }}</h3>
            </header>
            <div class="m-recipe__image">
              <img src="{{ fields["strMealThumb"] }}" alt="{{ fields["strMeal"] }}">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

When I debug with kint this is the output I get 
[image: Kint output]

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, Are strMeal and strMealThumb both part of the same meal

Comment: According to your kint output it's probably `fields.meal.strMeal`, and so on

Comment: @Clive I tried that and it doens't seem to work.

Comment: @user3127648 Yes, they are both part of the same meal.

Answer (score 1):

Sollution:

Associative array:

```
array_push($mealsArray, ["meal" =>
  [
    'strMeal' => $mealTitle,
    'strMealThumb' => $mealImage,
    'mealUrl' => $mealTitleUrl
  ]
]);
```

Twig:

```
{% for meal in meals %}
      {% for fields in meal %}
        <div class="u-col-md-3 u-col-xs-6">
          <div class="m-recipe">
            <a class="m-recipe__link" href="/recipes/{{ fields.mealUrl }}"></a>
            <header class="m-recipe__header u-margin-bottom">
              <h3>{{ fields.strMeal }}</h3>
            </header>
            <div class="m-recipe__image">
              <img src="{{ fields.strMealThumb }}" alt="{{ fields.strMeal }}">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

The return statement remains unchanged.